# асинхронный опрос оборудования в бесконечном цикле?

Tags: c#, async-await

Доброго времени суток!!

Имею задачу по опросу оборудования используя `SerialPort`. Будет 2 вида UI на WPF и WinForms. Сейчас отлаживаю на WinForms. В обработчике загрузке форму я открываю порт и передаю его в метод обработчика. Пока занимаю 1 порт но может понадобиться также запустить и другую обработку.

```
public async Task RunExchange(MasterSerialPort masterSerialPort)
{
    if (masterSerialPort == null)
        return;

    if (masterSerialPort.IsBusy)
        return;

    MasterSerialPortCashiers.IsBusy = true;                                                                                                          
    while(true)
    {
        foreach (var cashier in _cashiers)
        {
            var readProvider = new CashierReadDataProviderServer { InputData = cashier.Id };
            await MasterSerialPortCashiers.DataExchangeAsync(TimeRespawn, readProvider);

            //Обработка ответа и отправка результата.

            var writeProvider = new CashierWriteDataProviderServer { InputData = item };
            await MasterSerialPortCashiers.DataExchangeAsync(TimeRespawn, writeProvider);
        }
    }
}
```

Т.е. последовательное общение с кассирами с блокировками по `await`. 
 Проблем с UI нет так как код асинхронный, но смущает `while(true){...}`.
Может лучше навсегда занять поток из пула `Task.Run()`? или сделать еще как-то?

Comment: на первом же await поток перестанет существовать и станет цепочкой задач выполняющихся в пуле. Поэтому while..await совсем не то же что просто while {}

Comment: я и не собираюсь await-ом этот таск дожидаться. Т.е.  Task.Factory.StartNew(...) вернет мне задачу. я ее дожидаться не буду пусть 1 поток из пула занят всегда на фоне

Comment: async/await "разматывает" выполнение кода в одном потоке в цепочку задач. Для понимания как сделать у вас в вопросе не хватает знаний про соответствие "1 порт =1 оборудование или 1 порт = много оборудования".

Comment: 1 порт - 1 тип оборудования. т.е. в моем случае 6 кассовых аппаратов. если захочу опрашивать еще какой то тип напишу для него свой RunExchange.

Comment: Ну  если над архитектурой поработать то можно через DI внедрить нужные данные для другого оборудования. Но основной принцип такой 1-порт - 1 задача - 1 тип оборудования оправшивается последовательно.

Comment: В общем поясню суть. Пусть у вас 10 портов и вы делаете 10 Task.Run и не используется await = вы получили 10 активных *блокированных* в месте чтения/записи потоков. Если вы используете await (если это возможно), то эти 10 потоков дойдя до первого await освобождаются и вы имеете 0 блокированных потоков. Из этого следует, что асинхронный вариант лучше, а не "навсегда занять", а while (true) ничего не меняет в работе обоих вариантов

Comment: Т.е. можно оставить как есть. А вызываю  этот код без await CashierExchangeService.RunExchange(masterSerialPortCashiers);

Comment: то,  что вы вызываете этот код без await - не изменит его работу, но не позволит поймать исключения если они будут и приложение упадет. Потому либо обернуть внутри этого метода в поглощающий try..catch (плохо) либо снаружи сделать await при вызове этого метода. Много параллельных опросов - await Task.WhenAll. А вообще правило такое: есть вввод/вывод? - значит мы получим выгоду от асинхронности. нет ввода/вывода - в 99% случаев выгоды от await не получим

Comment: а вообще в принципе чем завершится задача в бесконечном цикле без токена отмены (не считая исключения). await Task.WhenAll даст нам возможность поймать это исключение это да это плюс. Ну класс SerialPort не переписали на async/await методы работы с портами а делать это на таймерах сейчас не хочется. По сути вы правы там весь стэк вызовов будет вызываться синхронно в основном потоке и только задержка на ожидание данных в порт приостановит выполнение.

Comment: Ничем не завершится - будет работать вечно, если не будет исключений и такая работа вполне себе нормально. Разница в том, что если у вас 100 таких потоков опроса, то без await оно потребует 100 потоков, а с await их постоянно будет освобождать и переиспользовать.

Comment: Вооо это я не учел, да точно ведь на время реальной блокировки поток опять будет доступен в пуле. СПАСИБО!!!

Comment: А не проще ли выделить отдельный поток и в нем по таймеру, предположим, каждые 500 млс выполнять то, что вы выполняете в while(true)? Или у Вас суперкритичные требования?

Comment: Раньше всегда на таймере делал. но ведь таймер это уже отдельный поток. а использование async/await на время блокировки позволяет освободить этот поток вот и все.

Comment: Просто вставьте в ваш цикл `while` строчку `await Task.Delay(300);`, вот вам и замена таймеру, не кушающая потоки, но при этом немного разгружающая устройство.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

> Проблем с UI нет так как код асинхронный, но смущает while(true){...}.
>   Может лучше навсегда занять поток из пула Task.Run()? или сделать еще
>   как-то?

Поток занимать не нужно, поскольку это попросту неэффективно, особенно если аппаратов у вас будет несколько. `async/await` в данном случае прекрасно подходит. Я бы добавил небольшую паузу между опросами оборудования, потому что скорее всего некоторая пауза между обращениями приемлема и позволит немного снизить нагрузку на систему и оборудование:

```
while (true)
{
    foreach (var cashier in _cashiers)
    {
        ...
    }

    await Task.Delay(300); // или любое другое подходящее значение
}
```

Плюс передал бы `CancellationToken` -- вам ведь в какой-то момент нужно будет останавливать опрос?

```
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
    foreach (var cashier in _cashiers)
    {
        ...
    }

    await Task.Delay(300);
}
```